# Best practice for object creation in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, builder, static-classes

For my unit tests I need a lot of specific, large (many fields) objects. I need multiple *different* instances for all my testclasses. As far as I know I have a few options and I was wondering what would be the best:

- extend the constructors of the classes but then I risk the telescoping pattern
- write methods in each testclass to create the object for me
- implement the [builder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html), but lose a lot of time refactoring my application
- use utility classes that create objects for me based on given parameters

I think the best option is to use the builder pattern, but this is the most difficult since I don't have a lot of time for refactoring. So I think the next best thing is using utility classes. Is this a good practice or are the better options? 
I aplogize if this is primairly opinion based.

Comment: Have you tried any existing framework which is developed for unit test? They may aid you, based on your technology used.

Comment: No I haven't tried any yet. Are there frameworks that create the needed objects? I don't really see the advantage in using frameworks for this.

Comment: The focus of unit test is for coverage and to ensure that under-all circumstances (meaning exceptional scenarios) the system does recovers. Like for C++, there is a framework CPPTest.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you'd benefit from the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Which is basically what you're suggesting in your last point.

There's nothing wrong with creating a specific factory just for your tests.

Comment: I thought tha factory pattern was used to create the desired implementation of a certain interface. That's not what I want, I'm trying to find the best and most re usable method to create (for example) a person with name, gender, ...

Comment: Maybe an abstract factory is overkill. But you can still create a factory which has a fairly advanced creator-method which possibly could reduse a lot of the manual parameter-passing, even randomize them although I'd guess that not a very good idea for a test-case. For example you could have a map with all the parameters stored in the factory and then pass in only that which you want to change into the creatormethod.

Answer (score 1):

if you still have no builder in your code this means one of 3 things: you have a simple CRUD, your code is really bad or your objects are created in a very few ways/few places. i assume the last case. so use factories - your last option. but if you have any logic involved in process of object creation then you should still refactor your code and use same logic/same factories in your production code and your tests. otherwise you risk testing objects that are completely different from what you have on production. and even if now you will copy/paste the logic to your tests then in a few months your test object will differ from your production objects.

by 'logic' i mean any kind on not null checking, assertions, preconditions, fields transformations etc